# solve high stolen memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, memory

I've a SQL Server 2012 SP2 with max memory set to 13GB but there is 8GB of stolen memory (*SQLServer:Memory Manager - Stolen Server Memory (KB)*). I know stolen memory is memory taken from the bufferpool to do sorting and hashing operations.

But how can I identify what process/request is using all that stolen memory, or what query is doing a lot of hashing/sorting?

**Update**
Further research showed that MEMORYCLERK_XE was using 4.3GB. This could be fixed by SP3. We will schedule this update and monitor if the problem is fixed.

Comment: You should first apply `SQL Server 2012 SP3` although this might not be related to your issue but many memory fixes are done from SP1 to SP3. Other question is are you really facing performance issue ? Stolen memory is not just only for sorting or hash operations it is for other uses as well. This memory is used for purpose other than database pages

Comment: Is there a way to see what's allocating the 8GB, maybe there's something I can finetune?
60% of my memory is 'stolen', is this a normal behavior?

Comment: Not that I know, because it not only include memory for `Sort and hash` but also for `store internal data structures such as locks, transaction context, and connection information`.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 2):

You could try querying various dmvs with the following script.

```
SELECT TEXT,
   request_time,
   grant_time,
   query_cost,
   timeout_sec,
   wait_order,
   wait_time_ms,
   group_id,
   requested_memory_kb,
   granted_memory_kb,
   required_memory_kb,
   used_memory_kb,
   max_used_memory_kb,
   ideal_memory_kb,
   query_plan,
   'all information >',
   *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants qmg
   OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) st
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) qp
```

It queries the following dmvs for information:

- [sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365393.aspx)
- [sys.dm_exec_sql_text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929.aspx)
- [sys.dm_exec_query_plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189747.aspx)

This script was handed over to me by [Ramesh Meyyappan](http://www.sqlworkshops.com) at a course on "SQL Server Performance Tuning and Optimisation" at Microsoft SA, Wallisellen, Switzerland.